# three singular points

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am trying to prove the following:

> Let $F$ be homogeneous polynomial of degree $3$ in $k[X, Y, T ]$ where $k$ is algebrically closed field. Assume that $V(F)$ has three
>   distinct singular points. Show that $V (F )$ is the union of three lines.

Any help will be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $F$ is a degree $3$ homogeneous polynomial. We will consider the following possibilities for $F:$

(1) $F$ is irreducible; (2) $F=fg,$ where $f, g$ are distinct irreducible homogeneous polynomials of degree 1 and 2 respectively; (3) $F=fg^2$ where $f,g$ are distinct irreducible homogeneous polynomials of degree 1; (4) $F=fgh,$ where $f,g,h$ are distinct irreducible homogeneous polynomials of degree 1; (5) $F=f^3,$ where $f$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree 1.

Now the condition that $V(F)$ has exactly three distinct singular points immediately rules out the cases (1), (3) and (5). For the case (2), $V(F)$ is a union of a line and a conic in $\mathbb P^2.$ So the number of possible singular points are $\leq 2.$ This leaves the only possibility:(4).

Comment: Could you explain why you eliminate the cases 1,3 and 5. Thank you very much..

Comment: For case (1), it is a smooth hypersurface in $\mathbb P^2.$ For case (5), it is a hypersurface in $\mathbb P^2,$ but it is singular (for example, the hypersurface given by $x^3=0$). Similar argument for the case (3) also (for example, $F=xy^2$).